# Visual Studio VC2013 enabling SSE4.1 without AVX

Tags: visual-c++

I have a rather simple question, but after searching quite some time I found no real answer yet. Microsoft suggests to enable AVX enhanced instruction set in order to also make use of SSE4 optimized code. 
Unfortunately, despite some readings, this enforces also use of an AVX capable CPU. Is there a way known to enable SSE4 without enforcing AVX in VC2013?
Background of this question is obvious I think, SSE4 is longer supported and only requires older CPU's (first from 2006 I think), while AVX requires CPU's from 2011. The dll in question only uses optimizations for SSE4, but for now I have to stick with SSE2 sacrificing performance in order to keep it working.

Comment: Do you want to rely on compiler optimizations for SSE4? Or you just want to use the intrinsics?

Comment: full optimization would be best, but using the intrinsics would be already nice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that `/arch:SSE2` flag adds support for SSE2 and later intrinsics. I don't have Visual Studio installed but this example works([`_mm_floor_ps`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531451%28v=vs.120%29.aspx) is SSE4 specific) :

```
#include <smmintrin.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    __declspec(align(16)) float values[4] = {1.3f, 2.1f, 4.3f, 5.1f};
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        cout << values[i] << ' ';
    cout << endl;

    __m128 x = _mm_load_ps(values);
    x = _mm_floor_ps(x);
    _mm_store_ps(values, x);

   for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        cout << values[i] << ' ';
    cout << endl;
}
```

You can try it online [here](http://webcompiler.cloudapp.net/).[image: Compile result]

Comment: thanks, that's already quite helpful! I took this example further and tried it to compile with /arch:IA32 parameter and it also compiles and works- while MS says "you must specify /arch:IA32 to disable generation of SSE and SSE2 instructions for x86 processors." - so I take it that intrinsics can be used no matter what's set there. This again rises again more questions about performance differences and the general usefulness of "enable enhanced instruction set" option. Nevertheless I'll keep the question open for now to see if someone has more ideas about full optimization.

Comment: After some more research- this is the one and only answer. The intrinisics work despite whats set there, for the optimization with "enable enhanced instruction set" seems to be no other option- although I've never seen any performance difference if setting this option for "some random code". But that's a different question to be asked here.